Is the quotation “The true shekinah is man” from the Talmud?
One of the quotes on the wall of the Library of Congress in Washington, D.C. is, “The true shekinah is man.” I was curious about the origin of that quote, but when I googled it, I found that it was attributed variously to the Talmud or St. John Chrysostom (quoted by Thomas Carlyle). I can't find any source that gives an actual citation or original text.
So is “The true shekinah is man” found in the Talmud? (I have also seen the variant “The true shekinah of G-d is man.”)

Sounds pretty christological tbh

Sounds like a poor translation. There are no search results that have both Ιωάννης Χρυσόστομος and Ταλμούδ in Greek.

No, it was from John Chrysostom. By the way, the guy was a rabid anti-Semite.

Chrysostom died in 407 CE. Talmud was completed around 500 CE.

Just as a clarification, I don't mean to say that Chrysostom and the Talmud bear any interrelation to one another. It just happens that online I've found claims that one or the other was the source.

It doesn't appear to be from the Talmud. According to John Hruschka, "Carlyle's Rabbinical Hero: Teufelsdröckh and the Midrashic Tradition", Carlyle Annual 13 (1992/1993), pp. 102-103, it appears to be strongly related to a quote from Laurence Sterne's "The Life and Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman" (AKA 'Tristram Shandy'), who brings, in turn, a paraphrase of a particular quote from Chrysostom's Homilies on Hebrews. Sterne wrote:

"Who made Man-... the Shekinah of the Divine presence, as Chrysostom [said]."

However, the notion of "true Shekinah" is unknown, leading Hruschka to suggest that either Carlyle misunderstood Sterne, or had a second, unknown source.

The statement itself is heresy in both Judaism and Christianity. It might have been conceived as a brutal humanist rephrasing of similar ideas found in both Talmud and John Chrysostom, who was at the origin of the Christian antisemitism as discussed by R. Eliezer Berkovitz Faith after the Holocaust, p. 40 - 41. It also appears resembling some of the doctrines of the heretical christian sects, such as Arianism or Nestorianism. The texts of nestorians were written in Aramaic and its later form Syriac, and some of their terminology looks similar to that of the Talmud. These texts became available to scholars at the end of XIX-th - beginning of the XXth century when the Library of Congress was built.
In Judaism Shechina represents revelation of Divine presence and it can never be the same as man. It can rest on a single man as several sayings in Mishna and Talmud hold:
Mishna Avos 3:2: Now I have no [scriptural proof for the presence of the Shekhinah] except [among] two, how [do we know] that even one who sits and studies Torah the Holy One, blessed be He, fixes his reward? As it is said: “though he sit alone and [meditate] in stillness, yet he takes [a reward] unto himself” (Lamentations 3:28).
Mishna Avos 3:6 How do we know that the same [i.e. presence of Shekhina] is true even of one [person]? As it is said: “In every place where I cause my name to be mentioned I [G-d] will come unto you and bless you” (Exodus 20:21).
Talmud Bavli Nedarim 40a And Ravin said that Rav said: From where is it derived that the Divine Presence is resting above the bed of the sick person? It is also as it is stated: “The Lord will support him upon the bed of suffering,” which indicates that G-d is actually over his bed.
Talmud Bavli Nedarim 38a Rabbi Yoḥanan said: The Holy One, Blessed be He, rests His Divine Presence only upon one who is mighty, and wealthy, and wise, and humble. And all of these qualities are derived from Moses. (Then the Talmud gives textual proofs).
The Hebrew term Shekhina is never used in the Greek Christian literature, although it is used in medieval Christian Kabbala as an extension of ideas in Guess 1 below. An analysis of Christian texts on the subject can be found, for example, in the article by the pastor Dan Miller "The True Shekina", who states "... to posit that “the true Shekinah is man” constitutes a brazen grab for G-d’s rightful place as sovereign of the universe." Since this is a Jewish site I will make two guesses if Chrysostom, one of the major comentators of the New Testament, could say something similar to the phrase in question or to one of the Talmudic statements.
Guess 1: Regarding Divine Presence itself see Chrysostom comments Homily 5 on Matthew 1:22-23 Matthew 1:22-23. (Older print edition).
Guess 2: There exist similar themes, which have been independently developed in both Judaism and Christianity, since both religions grew from analysis of the same texts. A book by Michal bar-Asher Segal "Early Christian Monastic Literature and the Babylonian Talmud" explores a number of such themes. Jesus in Christianity is likened to Moses. Thus, one can find a partial similarity between the quoted above statement of Rabbi Yoḥanan Nedarim 38a and Chrysostom's Homily 46 dicussing Matthew 11:29 (or older translation in print).


I think you are confusing the Christian concepts of "son of man" or "son of God" with the words "man of God." 2. The quote from Chrysostom seems misattributed. It looks like modern Greek, probably the words of the author of the site you linked, not a translation, since the archived version (I don't have access to the current page) only attributes this to him in the title, not the body of the text that appears to be a translation of an (unsourced) quote.


OK, addressed. I did not want to do it.

To be clear, I don't think an explanation of any Christian concept is necessary in an answer to this question, since it's not what the question is asking; if you don't want to do it there's no need to have it in your answer (and honestly, not being an expert in Christianity, I still don't understand the connection for or against "the true shekinah is man" in the new quotes either)

@ba the relation is clear, though the wording of it is crazy. In Christianity they allow only one person have shekhina and it is somewhat similar how we say that Moshe rabbeinu had shekhina. I.e. Christian authors of the phrase if they read both texts could have kept their religious view but with a use of a fancy aramaic word. Alternatively, they may not have even read the Talmud, but some of the heretical Nestorian (Church of the East) or Arian Christianity texts who indeed wrote in Aramaic and had doctrines like the one in the question (physical son).
